# Rust sorting algorithms (selection, bubble, quick, shell, merge)

Tags: performance, beginner, sorting, rust

I have written some sorting algorithms in Rust and wanted to see how terrible they were.

What I am looking for:

1. Bugs
2. Performance improvements
3. Idiomatic code
4. Maybe even a functional approach to the sorting algos
5. Why is the merge sort so slow? Is it my implementation?

Note you will need `rand = '*'` in your `Cargo.toml` for running tests/benches. All tests pass at this point and here are the benches from my machine.

```
test tests::bench_large_bubble_sort    ... bench:   1,294,490 ns/iter (+/- 188,917)
test tests::bench_large_merge_sort     ... bench:   1,196,096 ns/iter (+/- 141,654)
test tests::bench_large_quick_sort     ... bench:      70,173 ns/iter (+/- 11,150)
test tests::bench_large_selection_sort ... bench:   1,351,724 ns/iter (+/- 197,069)
test tests::bench_large_shell_sort     ... bench:      95,080 ns/iter (+/- 14,972)
test tests::bench_small_bubble_sort    ... bench:         923 ns/iter (+/- 118)
test tests::bench_small_merge_sort     ... bench:       4,479 ns/iter (+/- 743)
test tests::bench_small_quick_sort     ... bench:         824 ns/iter (+/- 103)
test tests::bench_small_selection_sort ... bench:         788 ns/iter (+/- 129)
test tests::bench_small_shell_sort     ... bench:         852 ns/iter (+/- 117)
```

---

```
#![feature(test)]
#![feature(step_by)]

fn selection_sort(mut values: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut min;
    for outer in 0..values.len() {
        min = outer;
        for inner in (outer + 1)..values.len() {
            if values[inner] < values[min] {
                min = inner;
            }
        }
        let temp = values[outer];
        values[outer] = values[min];
        values[min] = temp;
    }
    return values;
}

fn bubble_sort(mut values: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut swapped = true;
    let mut j = 0;
    while swapped {
        swapped = false;
        j += 1;
        for inner in 0..(values.len() - j) {
            if values[inner] > values[inner + 1] {
                let tmp = values[inner];
                values[inner] = values[inner + 1];
                values[inner + 1] = tmp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return values;
}

fn quick_sort(mut values: &mut Vec<i32>, start: Option<isize>, end: Option<isize>) {

    fn partition(mut partition_values: &mut Vec<i32>, start: isize, end: isize) -> isize {
        let mut pivot = start;
        for idx in (start + 1)..(end + 1) {
            if partition_values[idx as usize] <= partition_values[start as usize] {
                pivot += 1;
                let tmp = partition_values[idx as usize];
                partition_values[idx as usize] = partition_values[pivot as usize];
                partition_values[pivot as usize] = tmp;
            }
        }
        let tmp = partition_values[start as usize];
        partition_values[start as usize] = partition_values[pivot as usize];
        partition_values[pivot as usize] = tmp;
        return pivot;
    }

    let start_val = start.unwrap_or(0);
    let end_val = end.unwrap_or((values.len() - 1) as isize);
    if start_val >= end_val {
        return;
    }
    let pivot = partition(values, start_val, end_val);
    quick_sort(values, Some(start_val), Some(pivot - 1));
    quick_sort(values, Some(pivot + 1), Some(end_val));
}

fn shell_sort(mut values: &mut Vec<i32>) {
    fn sort_gap_insertation(mut values: &mut Vec<i32>, start: usize, gap: usize) {
        for i in ((start + gap)..values.len()).step_by(gap) {
            let val_current = values[i];
            let mut pos = i;

            while pos >= gap && values[pos - gap] > val_current {
                values[pos] = values[pos - gap];
                pos = pos - gap;
            }
            values[pos] = val_current;
        }
    }

    let mut count_sublist = values.len() / 2;
    while count_sublist > 0 {
        for pos_start in 0..count_sublist {
            sort_gap_insertation(values, pos_start, count_sublist);
        }
        count_sublist /= 2;
    }

}

fn merge_sort(values: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    fn merge(left: Vec<i32>, right: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
        if left.len() == 0 {
            return right;
        }
        if right.len() == 0 {
            return left;
        }
        if left[0] < right[0] {
            let mut v = Vec::new();
            v.push(left[0]);
            v.extend(merge(left[1..].to_vec(), right));
            return v;
        }
        let mut v = Vec::new();
        v.push(right[0]);
        v.extend(merge(left, right[1..].to_vec()));
        return v;
    }

    if values.len() <= 1 {
        return values;
    }
    let mid = values.len() / 2;
    let left = merge_sort(values[..mid].to_vec());
    let right = merge_sort(values[mid..].to_vec());
    return merge(left, right);
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![3, 2, 1];
    println!("{:?}", selection_sort(v));
    let v = vec![1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 6, 10, 1000, 10000, 5, 6, 6, 12];
    println!("{:?}", selection_sort(v));

    let v = vec![3, 2, 1];
    println!("{:?}", bubble_sort(v));
    let v = vec![1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 6, 10, 1000, 10000, 5, 6, 6, 12];
    println!("{:?}", bubble_sort(v));

    let mut v = vec![1, 5, 1, 5, 6, 0, 10, -5];
    quick_sort(&mut v, None, None);
    println!("{:?}", v);

    let mut v = vec![1, 5, 1, 5, 6, 0, 10, -5];
    shell_sort(&mut v);
    println!("{:?}", v);

    let v = vec![1, 5, 1, 5, 6, 0, 10, -5];
    println!("{:?}", merge_sort(v));

}

#[cfg(test)]
extern crate test;
#[cfg(test)]
extern crate rand;

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use test::Bencher;
    use rand::{self, Rng};

    #[test]
    fn test_selection_sort() {
        let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
        let v: Vec<i32> = rng.gen_iter::<i32>().take(1000).collect();
        let result = super::selection_sort(v);
        for i in 0..result.len() - 1 {
            assert!(result[i] <= result[i + 1]);
        }
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_large_selection_sort(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
            let v: Vec<i32> = rng.gen_iter::<i32>().take(1000).collect();
            super::selection_sort(v);
        })
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_small_selection_sort(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
            let v: Vec<i32> = rng.gen_iter::<i32>().take(15).collect();
            super::selection_sort(v);
        })
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_bubble_sort() {
        let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
        let v: Vec<i32> = rng.gen_iter::<i32>().take(1000).collect();
        let result = super::bubble_sort(v);
        for i in 0..result.len() - 1 {
            assert!(result[i] <= result[i + 1])
        }
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_large_bubble_sort(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
            let v: Vec<i32> = rng.gen_iter::<i32>().take(1000).collect();
            super::bubble_sort(v);
        })
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_small_bubble_sort(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
            let v: Vec<i32> = rng.gen_iter::<i32>().take(15).collect();
            super::bubble_sort(v);
        })
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_quick_sort() {
        let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
        let mut v: Vec<i32> = rng.gen_iter::<i32>().take(1000).collect();
        super::quick_sort(&mut v, None, None);
        for i in 0..v.len() - 1 {
            assert!(v[i] <= v[i + 1]);
        }
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_large_quick_sort(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
            let mut v: Vec<i32> = rng.gen_iter::<i32>().take(1000).collect();
            super::quick_sort(&mut v, None, None);
        })
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_small_quick_sort(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
            let mut v: Vec<i32> = rng.gen_iter::<i32>().take(15).collect();
            super::quick_sort(&mut v, None, None);
        })
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_shell_sort() {
        let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
        let mut v: Vec<i32> = rng.gen_iter::<i32>().take(1000).collect();
        super::shell_sort(&mut v);
        for i in 0..v.len() - 1 {
            assert!(v[i] <= v[i + 1]);
        }
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_large_shell_sort(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
            let mut v: Vec<i32> = rng.gen_iter::<i32>().take(1000).collect();
            super::shell_sort(&mut v);
        })
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_small_shell_sort(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
            let mut v: Vec<i32> = rng.gen_iter::<i32>().take(15).collect();
            super::shell_sort(&mut v);
        })
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_merge_sort() {
        let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
        let v: Vec<i32> = rng.gen_iter::<i32>().take(1000).collect();
        let result = super::merge_sort(v);
        for i in 0..result.len() - 1 {
            assert!(result[i] <= result[i + 1]);
        }
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_large_merge_sort(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
            let v: Vec<i32> = rng.gen_iter::<i32>().take(1000).collect();
            super::merge_sort(v);
        })
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_small_merge_sort(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
            let v: Vec<i32> = rng.gen_iter::<i32>().take(15).collect();
            super::merge_sort(v);
        })
    }
}
```

I have also created a version of this using traits instead of free functions. I wasn't able to get `merge_sort` working yet but here are the rest.

```
#![feature(test)]
#![feature(step_by)]
use std::cmp::Ord;
use std::clone::Clone;

trait SelectSortable {
    fn selection_sort(&mut self);
}

impl<T: Ord + Clone + PartialEq> SelectSortable for Vec<T> {
    fn selection_sort(&mut self) {
        let mut min;
        for outer in 0..self.len() {
            min = outer;
            for inner in (outer + 1)..self.len() {
                if self[inner] < self[min] {
                    min = inner;
                }
            }
            let temp = self[outer].clone();
            self[outer] = self[min].clone();
            self[min] = temp;
        }
    }
}

trait BubbleSortable {
    fn bubble_sort(&mut self);
}

impl<T: Ord + Clone + PartialEq> BubbleSortable for Vec<T> {
    fn bubble_sort(&mut self) {
        let mut swapped = true;
        let mut j = 0;
        while swapped {
            swapped = false;
            j += 1;
            for inner in 0..(self.len() - j) {
                if self[inner] > self[inner + 1] {
                    let temp = self[inner].clone();
                    self[inner] = self[inner + 1].clone();
                    self[inner + 1] = temp;
                    swapped = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

trait QuickSortable {
    fn quick_sort(&mut self, start: Option<isize>, end: Option<isize>);
    fn _partition(&mut self, start: isize, end: isize) -> isize;
}

impl<T: Ord + Clone + PartialEq> QuickSortable for Vec<T> {
    fn _partition(&mut self, start: isize, end: isize) -> isize {
        let mut pivot = start;
        for idx in (start + 1)..(end + 1) {
            if self[idx as usize] <= self[start as usize] {
                pivot += 1;
                let tmp = self[idx as usize].clone();
                self[idx as usize] = self[pivot as usize].clone();
                self[pivot as usize] = tmp;
            }
        }
        let tmp = self[start as usize].clone();
        self[start as usize] = self[pivot as usize].clone();
        self[pivot as usize] = tmp;
        return pivot;
    }


    fn quick_sort(&mut self, start: Option<isize>, end: Option<isize>) {

        let start_val = start.unwrap_or(0);
        let end_val = end.unwrap_or((self.len() - 1) as isize);
        if start_val >= end_val {
            return;
        }
        let pivot = self._partition(start_val, end_val);
        self.quick_sort(Some(start_val), Some(pivot - 1));
        self.quick_sort(Some(pivot + 1), Some(end_val));
    }
}

trait ShellShortable {
    fn shell_sort(&mut self);
    fn _gap_insert(&mut self, start: usize, gap: usize);
}

impl<T: Ord + Clone + PartialEq> ShellShortable for Vec<T> {
    fn _gap_insert(&mut self, start: usize, gap: usize) {
        for i in ((start + gap)..self.len()).step_by(gap) {
            let val_current = self[i].clone();
            let mut pos = i;

            while pos >= gap && self[pos - gap] > val_current {
                self[pos] = self[pos - gap].clone();
                pos = pos - gap;
            }
            self[pos] = val_current;
        }
    }

    fn shell_sort(&mut self) {
        let mut count_sublist = self.len() / 2;
        while count_sublist > 0 {
            for pos_start in 0..count_sublist {
                self._gap_insert(pos_start, count_sublist);
            }
            count_sublist /= 2;
        }

    }
}


fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![3, 2, 1];
    v.selection_sort();
    println!("{:?}", v);

    let mut v = vec![3, 2, 1];
    v.bubble_sort();
    println!("{:?}", v);
    let mut v = vec![1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 6, 10, 1000, 10000, 5, 6, 6, 12];
    v.bubble_sort();
    println!("{:?}", v);

    let mut v = vec![1, 5, 1, 5, 6, 0, 10, -5];
    v.quick_sort(None, None);
    println!("{:?}", v);

    let mut v = vec![1, 5, 1, 5, 6, 0, 10, -5];
    v.shell_sort();
    println!("{:?}", v);
}

#[cfg(test)]
extern crate test;
#[cfg(test)]
extern crate rand;

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use test::Bencher;
    use rand::{self, Rng};
    use super::{SelectSortable, BubbleSortable, QuickSortable, ShellShortable};

    #[test]
    fn test_selection_sort() {
        let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
        let mut v: Vec<i32> = rng.gen_iter::<i32>().take(1000).collect();
        v.selection_sort();
        for i in 0..v.len() - 1 {
            assert!(v[i] <= v[i + 1]);
        }
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_large_selection_sort(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
            let mut v: Vec<i32> = rng.gen_iter::<i32>().take(1000).collect();
            v.selection_sort();
        })
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_small_selection_sort(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
            let mut v: Vec<i32> = rng.gen_iter::<i32>().take(15).collect();
            v.selection_sort();
        })
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_bubble_sort() {
        let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
        let mut v: Vec<i32> = rng.gen_iter::<i32>().take(1000).collect();
        v.bubble_sort();
        for i in 0..v.len() - 1 {
            assert!(v[i] <= v[i + 1])
        }
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_large_bubble_sort(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
            let mut v: Vec<i32> = rng.gen_iter::<i32>().take(1000).collect();
            v.bubble_sort();
        })
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_small_bubble_sort(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
            let mut v: Vec<i32> = rng.gen_iter::<i32>().take(15).collect();
            v.bubble_sort();
        })
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_quick_sort() {
        let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
        let mut v: Vec<i32> = rng.gen_iter::<i32>().take(1000).collect();
        v.quick_sort(None, None);
        for i in 0..v.len() - 1 {
            assert!(v[i] <= v[i + 1]);
        }
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_large_quick_sort(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
            let mut v: Vec<i32> = rng.gen_iter::<i32>().take(1000).collect();
            v.quick_sort(None, None);
        })
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_small_quick_sort(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
            let mut v: Vec<i32> = rng.gen_iter::<i32>().take(15).collect();
            v.quick_sort(None, None);
        })
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_shell_sort() {
        let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
        let mut v: Vec<i32> = rng.gen_iter::<i32>().take(1000).collect();
        v.shell_sort();
        for i in 0..v.len() - 1 {
            assert!(v[i] <= v[i + 1]);
        }
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_large_shell_sort(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
            let mut v: Vec<i32> = rng.gen_iter::<i32>().take(1000).collect();
            v.shell_sort();
        })
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_small_shell_sort(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
            let mut v: Vec<i32> = rng.gen_iter::<i32>().take(15).collect();
            v.shell_sort();
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `merge` function in your merge sort is \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$ (it's meant to be \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$) because

```
v.extend(merge(left[1..].to_vec(), right));
```

uses `extend`, which takes \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ time, and you do it \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ times, which makes \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$ total.

The merge is normally implemented by pushing one element at a time to a mutable buffer.

Comment: Could you provide an example? I am not sure I know how to do such a task.

Comment: @electrometro Here's someone else's version: https://github.com/Alexanderbez/rust-merge-sort/blob/master/src/merge_sort.rs#L12-L28. Mine would be mostly the same.